# How to perform multi-class classification of 1000+ factors using 'libsvm' package in R

Tags: r, libsvm, multiclass-classification

Below is the implementation in "**svm**"

```
svm_model<-(data_one[,1]~.,data=data_one,method="C-classification",kernel = "linear")
```

Where,

*data_one[,1] -> is the target class with 1000+ factors.*

since it has large number of factors to classify,
the **svm** algorithm throws the error as follows,

```
Error in double(nrow(newdata) * object$nclasses * (object$nclasses - 1)/2) : 
vector size specified is too large
```

As far i know **libsvm** works well with multi-class target class., can anyone help me in doing the same?